Memory Leak in Rxjs Map function when creating new objects
I am using the Rxjs lib in Angular to get data from the backend and show it on a map. The message rate can be fast: 10 messages/sec. The backend data object is mapped, and a new MapAsset object is created progressively for each update by the MapAsset.fromAsset method (typically, one object is updated at a time).
Please take a look at the memory snapshot of the system after running the application with updates for a few mins. The system has 21,000 items. But after a few mins amount of MapAsset object is close to 2 million. The system eventually ends up crashing.
How do we fix this memory issue?
 const assets$ = this.getAllAssets();
 const mapAssets$ = assets$
      .pipe(
        map(assets => {
          return assets
            .map(asset => MapAsset.fromAsset(asset, transformMatrix)); 
        }),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        shareReplay(),
      );


getAllAssets(): Observable<Asset[]> {
    return this.store.select(state => state.assetListState.assetData)
      .pipe(
        map(assets => Array.from(assets.values())),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        shareReplay(),
      );
  }


Can you provide the code showing how is the assets$ variable initialized and how is its value updated?

@mat.hudak I have updated the post now. We fetch data using HTTP calls for each update and apply the changes to the redux store.

There are mulitple open points:

How does your reducer looks like? I guess, you are just adding the new assets to the state instead of updating them.
Do you have considered to use the ngrx/entity package?
Why do you need to map the assets? Is there a specific business logic behind it? Or do you do it, because you allways map objects like on the backend?
Why do you have a function getAllAssets() instead of just use a selector with an async pipe?



reducer is a map with id and object, when an item changes we set that newData.set(payload.id.toString(), payload); and update the store
No 3. Yes, the x, and y positions need to be converted to UI coordinated before being drawn on the map.  4. reuse the logic


shareReplay() remembers all past values, I think. Are you sure you don't want shareReplay(1) instead?

Also, distinctUntilChanged() without the optional comparator argument will have no effect in getAllAssets() because every time the store emits something, the map operator creates a new array object.

You can try to configure shareReplay like this:
shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true });
bufferSize will help you control the amount of previous values ​​that will be retransmitted to new subscribers. If you put bufferSize: 1 only the last value emitted by the Observable will be retransmitted, but you leave the number you want, the smaller the number, the less memory accumulated. This will help you save memory.
refCount will help you free up memory and control data emission. With refCount: true It only emits data when it has at least one subscriber and when all subscribers cancel their subscriptions, the Observable completes itself and releases the associated resources. Without this configuration, the Observable can continue emitting values ​​and taking up memory even without any subscribers.
